# Should a tag be created for google-oauth-1.0a or should existing tag wiki be edited?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

There exists on Stack Overflow a tag called [google-oauth](/questions/tagged/google-oauth) and its description talks solely about the Google OAuth 2.0 implementation.

However, the [google-oauth-java-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/wiki/DeveloperGuide) library supports both OAuth 1.0a and OAuth 2.0.

Should the existing tag wiki be modified to talk of both OAuth 1.0a and OAuth 2.0, or should a new [google-oauth-1.0a](/questions/tagged/google-oauth-1.0a) tag be created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the question about the library itself?  There are already tags for [google-http-java-client](/questions/tagged/google-http-java-client) and [google-api-java-client](/questions/tagged/google-api-java-client), so a similar tag for the `google-oauth-java-client` library is probably a safe choice.

Do not hijack or duplicate the existing [google-oauth](/questions/tagged/google-oauth) tag, as it is not about the one specific Java-only library you're worried about.

Comment: The wiki for the google-oauth tag talks exclusively about OAuth 2.0. Surely it needs to mention that Google's OAuth libraries support version 1.0a too?

Comment: The `google-oauth` tag **is not** about Google's official libraries.  Google has [deprecated their support for OAuth 1](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth).  The tag wiki should probably not encourage use of OAuth 1.  If you want a tag for the one specific Google-created library that supports both OAuth 1 and 2, then create a tag for *that library*.